# How to make Bootstrap 5 Floating Label work in Contact Form 7?

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form-7, bootstrap-5

I can't get the new form feature to work, Floating labels (Bootstrap 5) in Contact Form 7 (Wordpress), the issue is that it breaks when a  tag is added inside the  tag, I think, idk.

Bootstrap template:

```
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
  <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
</div>
```

[View in getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/floating-labels/#example)

Contact Form 7 example in editor:

```
<div class="form-floating mb-3"> [email emailExample id:floatingInput class:form-control]
  <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
</div>
```

Contact Form 7 example after:

```
<div class="form-floating my-3">
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap ignore">
    <input type="email" name="ignore" value="" size="40" id="floatingInput" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-email form-control" aria-invalid="false">
  </span>
  <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution. Tweek class if needed

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', function($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('/<(span).*?class="\s*(?:.*\s)?wpcf7-form-control-wrap(?:\s[^"]+)?\s*"[^\>]*>(.*)<\/\1>/i', '\2', $content);
    $content = str_replace('<br />', '', $content);
    return $content;
});
```

Comment: This works for floating labels but then error classes don't work anymore

Comment: It doesn't work, the plugin stops working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to remove `<P>` and `<SPAN>` from form.

CF7 give us:

```
define('WPCF7_AUTOP',false);
```

to remove P, but for SPAN, you have to add this line in functions.php

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', function($content) {
$content = preg_replace('/<(span).*?class="\s*(?:.*\s)?wpcf7-form-control-wrap(?:\s[^"]+)?\s*"[^\>]*>(.*)<\/\1>/i', '\2', $content);
return $content; });
```

Now, in CF7, you can use

```
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
[text* your-firstname class:form-control id:your-firstname placeholder "Nume*"]
<label for="your-firstname">Nume*</label>
</div>
```

Floating labels will works as aspected but I agree with @Marko, using this hack, **will not to display errors** for missing fields.

Luca

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suscribe to Aculine's answer, and it's true that CF7 validation is lost, but we can add it back as follows.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col col-12">
        <div class="form-floating mb-4 wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="form-email">
          [email* form-email class:form-control placeholder "Email (required)"]
          <label for="form-email">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The previous code is the code that I added in the form template (wp-admin > contacto form 7 > form template), to the div with the class "form-floating" I add the class "wpcf7-form-control-wrap", the same class as the spam we removed with the filter, and the data-name, which is equal to the input name.

Ajax validation it works again :)